# How to filter ListView by character instead of exact word using SearchView?

Tags: android, listview

I have an SearchView(v7) and Listview. Once user type anything in SearchView the result is produced and I populate in Listview. All works but problem is **I have to write exact that word which is present in Listview**.

Now, I want when user type any matching character from our ListView data that matching result will show.

For example, when I type letter I the  result will be following.

1) mitesh

2) vidhi

3) ravi

4) Ravi P

5) Tushar prajapati

etc.

Uppercase and lowercase letter not matter as of now. How can I achieve this?

Comment: possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23911317/searchview-auto-submit-after-couple-of-letters-or-seconds

Comment: [check this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30429439/6559031)

Answer (score 0):

try this code :

```
 TextWatcher edtSearchTextTextWatcher = new TextWatcher() {

        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        }

        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
        }

        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            String text = edtSearchText.getText().toString().trim();
            onSearchTextChanged(text);
        }
    };

    private void onSearchTextChanged(String text) {
        if (adapter!= null)
            adapter.filter(text);
    }


public void filter(final String text) {

        // Searching could be complex..so we will dispatch it to a different thread...
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                // Clear the filter list
                filterList.clear();

                // If there is no search value, then add all original list items to filter list
                if (TextUtils.isEmpty(text)) {

                    filterList.addAll(inspectionsList);

                } else {
                    // Iterate in the original List and add it to filter list...
                    for (ClsInspection item : inspectionsList) {
                        if (item.getClientName().toLowerCase().contains(text.toLowerCase()) || item.getInspectorsName().toLowerCase().contains(text.toLowerCase())
                                || item.getAddesss().toLowerCase().contains(text.toLowerCase())) {
                            // Adding Matched items
                            filterList.add(item);
                        }
                    }
                }

                // Set on UI Thread
                (fragment.getActivity()).runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        // Notify the List that the DataSet has changed...
                        notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
                });

            }
        }).start();

    }


private List<String> inspectionsList = new ArrayList<>();
private List<String> filterList = new ArrayList<>();

public adapter( List<String> inspectionsList) {
        this.inspectionsList = inspectionsList;
        this.filterList.addAll(inspectionsList);
    }
```

Comment: okay. but i use built in searchView and result is shown in resultActivity. i used  google docs approch here is an link https://developer.android.com/training/search/setup.html

Comment: and i don't think this is my requirement.sorry this answer not helpful to me.

Comment: ok...but instead of using default searchview , try using edittext as search , it will search faster and will work smoother

Comment: yes.but i like material searchview because i love material things.anyway thanks for answer i will find my self and if i got answer i will put answer here .so everyone can learned from here.

Answer (score 0):

at first you should use RecylerView instead of ListView. and inside `onQueryTextChange` method use this codes

```
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {

                newText = newText.toLowerCase() ;
                List<String> searchnames = new ArrayList<>() ;

                for(int i = 0 ; i < names.length ; i++){
                    String name = names[i].toLowerCase() ;
                    if(name.contains(newText)){
                        searchnames.add(name) ;
                    }
                }
                sampleRecylerAdapter.setFilter(searchnames);
                return true;
            }
```

here,  `names` is array with collection of string. and `sampleRecylerAdapter.setFilter(searchnames);` here setFilter() is method from RecylerViewAdapter class.

here is the all codes for RecylerviewAdapter :

```
public class SampleRecylerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<SampleRecylerAdapter.SampleRecylerViewHolder> {

    private final LayoutInflater inflater;
    private Context context ;
    private  List<String> name = Collections.emptyList() ;


    public SampleRecylerAdapter(Context context, List<String> name){
        this.context = context ;
        this.name = name ;
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context) ;
    }

    @Override
    public SampleRecylerViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_names, parent, false) ;
        SampleRecylerViewHolder sampleRecylerViewHolder = new SampleRecylerViewHolder(view);
        return sampleRecylerViewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(SampleRecylerViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.textView.setText(name.get(position));
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return name.size();
    }

    public class SampleRecylerViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        TextView textView ;
        public SampleRecylerViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            textView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.mynames) ;
        }
    }

    public void setFilter(List<String> mynames){
        name = new ArrayList<>() ;
        name.addAll(mynames) ;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

try to use your codes in this way. i hope it may helps you to solve the problem. let me know if you get any problem.

Answer (score 0):

works well with any text listener I have used edittext in this case

```
messageBoxView.alertdialog_edittext.addTextChangedListener(object : TextWatcher {
        override fun afterTextChanged(s: Editable?) {
            //adapter.getFilter().filter(s) ;

            val sr = s.toString().toLowerCase(Locale.ROOT)
            val newList: ArrayList<String> = ArrayList()
            //listItems is current list<String> inside adapter before searching
            for (list_item in listItems){
                val nocaps_item = list_item?.toLowerCase(Locale.ROOT)
                if(nocaps_item?.contains(sr)!!){
                    newList.add(list_item)
                }
            }
            val adapterNew: ArrayAdapter<String?> = ArrayAdapter(
                requireContext(),
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_single_choice,
                newList as List<String?>
            )
            messageBoxView.alertdialog_Listview.adapter = adapterNew

        }

        override fun beforeTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, count: Int, after: Int) {
        }

        override fun onTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, before: Int, count: Int) {
        }
    })
```